# create mozilla firefox addon using addon builder

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to create FF addon using online addon builder to access browser history,cache contents. Can i create such addon by directly writing javascript code in "name.js" file in builder? Or any other files is also required to be created except "name.js"? I am very new in this addon development.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of addons

Extensions: JavaScript and XUL. You can get started [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension)

Plugins: NPAPI, the Gecko Plugin API. You can read the complete guide [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference).

There is a nice [wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder) for generating extension skeletons.

Basiclly, if you are using this wizard, you will need to know primarly JavaScript.